# How to fix an UTF-8 double encoded XML file

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8

I have a XML file when seem to consist double encoded UTF-8 Character. For Example the “Gesch....ft” part in then hex dump should be Geschäft:

```
00009f0: 4365 6c6c 3e3c 4861 7368 4365 6c6c 3e3c  Cell><HashCell><
0000a00: 5374 7220 7661 6c75 653d 2253 746f 7265  Str value="Store
0000a10: 735f 4d65 6e75 222f 3e3c 5374 7220 7661  s_Menu"/><Str va
0000a20: 6c75 653d 2247 6573 6368 c383 c2a4 6674  lue="Gesch....ft
0000a30: 6522 2f3e 3c2f 4861 7368 4365 6c6c 3e3c  e"/></HashCell><
0000a40: 4861 7368 4365 6c6c 3e3c 5374 7220 7661  HashCell><Str va
```

I found a quite a few ways to fix UTF-8 double encoded databases, filenames or data streams. However I found nothing on fixing a plain text or XML file.

Comment: And how would I do that? Which tool to use? Which parameters to use? — Don't answer, I figured it out myself.

Comment: I was working on it... Just decode it (assuming only 1- and 2-byte sequences)

Answer (score 2):

To remove the double-encoding, you need to convert the file from UTF-8 to the character set that was wrongly used as the source character set when the second conversion to utf8 was done.

For German and other western European languages, your best bet is to use "Windows-1252" or "CP1252". It is the same as Latin-1, except that it has a few more characters, and these would produce errors when trying to convert to Latin-1.

There are several tools you can use to remove the double-encoding. On Mac and Linux, `iconv` is installed by default, so you can try

```
iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 $YourFile > $NewFile
```

However, if your file also starts with a BOM ([Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), you will probably get this error:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
```

In that case, use `uconv` instead, which takes about the same arguments, but does handle the BOM at the start of the file :

```
uconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 $YourFile > $NewFile
```

On Debian-based Linux distributions, it comes with

```
apt install icu-devtools
```

On Mac, it can be installed with `brew`:

```
brew install icu4c
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it on UNIX™. The following four lines in a Z-Shell script will to it:

```
#!/bin/zsh
setopt No_Err_Exit
iconv -f "UTF-8" -t "ISO-8859-1" "${1}" >"${1}.new"
mv "${1}"       "${1}.old"
mv "${1}.new"   "${1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the double-encoding will only yield 2-byte utf8-sequences (you could add a check for this), quick & dirty:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
int state,ch;
unsigned val;

for(state = 0; ;  ) {
    ch = getc(stdin);
    if (ch==EOF) break;
    switch(state) {
    case 0:
            if ((ch & 0xe0) == 0xc0) {
                    val = (ch & 0x1f) << 6;
                    state = 1;
                    }
            else putc( ch, stdout);
            break;
    case 1:
            val |= (ch & 0x3f);
            putc(val, stdout);
            state = 0;
            break;
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

---

This has the additional advantage that there is no checking if the resulting byte is a valid code point (which it need not be)
Result:

---

```
$ ./a.out < gesel.in > gesel.out
$ hexdump -C gesel.in
00000000  47 65 73 65 6c c3 83 c2  a4 66 74 65 0a           |Gesel....fte.|
0000000d
$ hexdump -C gesel.out
00000000  47 65 73 65 6c c3 a4 66  74 65 0a                 |Gesel..fte.|
0000000b
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not double UTF-8 encoded - it's a UTF-8 file that's been decoded as ISO-8859-1, then saved in UTF-8 encoded. Aka. Mojibake.

To fix this in Python do:

```
import io
with io.open('mojibake.xml', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as mojibaked_input_file:
    input_baked = mojibaked_input_file.read()
    # Reverse the wrong interpretation
    input_fixed = input_baked.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')

    mojibaked_input_file.seek(0)
    mojibaked_input_file.truncate()
    mojibaked_input_file.write(input_fixed)
```